Solving a set of Non-Linear equations by fitting to a dataset
I am trying to solve the following set of equations:
0 = AP + T - X
Where X, P and T are 3D vectors and A is a 3x3 DCM matrix.
I have a dataset of values of X and their corresponding P's. (In the code P = [x_p, y_p, 1], T = [x_t, y_t, z_t] and X = [x, y, z]). I am trying to find the angles in the rotation matrix (psi, theta, phi) and T that best fit my data points.
I am doing this in the context of trying to obtain the position and attitude of a camera based on an image it has taken of a calibration target that has a set of features with coordinates that are known and therefore giving us the coordinates in the world frame X and the image coordinates P. Using a pinhole model of a camera.

I have tried to solve this using a least squares regression using SciPy however I am not getting feasible results and I'm not sure if I am passing the data to the function correctly and actually finding the values of the variables in vars which minimize the residuals for all the data points.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def calibrate(coords, img_path, pixel_size = 3.5/1280):

    p_x = coords[:,0]; p_y = coords[:,1]
    x   = coords[:,2]; y   = coords[:,3]; z = coords[:,4]
   
    img_shape =  ( 1024, 1280)
            
    
    def equations(vars):
        x_t, y_t, z_t, phi, theta, psi, f = vars

        x_p = ( p_x - img_shape[1]/2)*pixel_size/f
        y_p = (-p_y + img_shape[0]/2)*pixel_size/f

        zc = np.sqrt((x_t - x)**2 + (y_t - y)**2 + (z_t - z)**2)

        f1 = (( m.cos(psi) * m.cos(theta)) * x_p + 
              (-m.sin(psi) * m.cos(phi) + m.cos(psi) * m.sin(theta) * m.cos(phi)) * y_p + 
              ( m.sin(psi) * m.sin(phi) + m.cos(psi) * m.sin(theta) * m.cos(phi))) * zc + x_t - x
        
        f2 = (( m.sin(psi) * m.sin(theta)) * x_p + 
              ( m.cos(psi) * m.cos(phi) + m.sin(psi) * m.sin(theta) * m.sin(phi)) * y_p + 
              (-m.cos(psi) * m.sin(phi) + m.sin(psi) * m.sin(theta) * m.cos(phi))) * zc + y_t - y
        
        f3 = ((-m.sin(theta)) * x_p + 
              ( m.cos(theta) * m.sin(phi)) * y_p + 
              ( m.cos(theta) * m.cos(phi))) * zc + z_t - z

        return np.hstack([f1, f2, f3]) 
    
    result = least_squares(
                            fun = equations, x0  = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5),
                            max_nfev= 100, loss='soft_l1', 
                            bounds= ([-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, 2.5], [np.inf,              
np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 30])
                        )

    values = result.x
    values[3:-2] = (values[3:-2]*180/np.pi)%360

    print(result.message)
    print('x_t, y_t, z_t = ', values[0:3])
    print('phi, theta, psi = ', values[3:-1])
    print('f = ', values[-1])
    print('Nb of iterations = ', result.nfev)
    return values

using the following data:
coords = np.array([[ 234,  347,   30,   25,    8],[ 981,  336,  -40,   25,    8],[1011,  607,  -40,    0,   -8],[ 249,  619,   30,    0,   -8],[ 240,  455,   30,   15,    0],[ 943,  443,  -35,   15,    0],[ 688,  612,  -10,    0,   -8],[ 675,  448,  -10,   15,    0],[ 665,  340,  -10,   25,    8],[ 234,  347,   30,   25,    8],[ 981,  336,  -40,   25,    8],[1011,  607,  -40,    0,   -8],[ 249,  619,   30,    0,   -8],[ 240, 455,   30,   15,    0],[ 943,  443,  -35,   15,    0],[ 688,  612,  -10,    0,   -8],[ 675,  448, -10,   15,    0],[ 665,  340,  -10,   25,    8]])


What is the variable being solved for?  Not clear.

And why do you call that a set of "Non-linear equations"? As far as I can see, everything is linear heae. AP+T-X is linear. Maybe those linear equations are an approximation of non-linear ones. But you said nothing of it, and you were right, since that would be irreleveant to your question, that is to solve a linear equation. Or maybe you say "non linear", because it cannot be solved exactly (because it has non exact solution). But it is still linear.

@chrslg I am trying to solve for the angles in the rotation matrix, which as far as I understand makes it a non linear equation due to the trig functions?

What makes you think that your output is not feasible?

I've written out a version of your implementation that's reframed as being vectorised and using easier-to-read matrices, but without knowing why you think the output is infeasible, it will be difficult to validate this.

@Reinderien I think that they are infeasible because from the image used for the calibration (with the +ve Z axis pointing into the page) we can see that z_t should be negative. Additionally when I substitute the values of x_t, y_t, z_t, psi, theta and phi I found into the original equation it does not fit the data.

@chrslg It's nonlinear due to the zc norm and multiplying it in. zc relies on xyz_t and the latter are degrees of freedom, and they multiply into a function of f which is also a degree of freedom.

@Theo Can you confirm that it was intentional for zc to be multiplied into the x_p and y_p terms? Can you show how this formula was constructed, and what each of the vectors means?

Also can you confirm whether you meant 1042 and not 1024?

@Reinderien Yes zc should multiply into both terms, in the equation at the top zc multiplies the whole AP term. You are correct it should be 1024, sorry for the typo. The set of equations I'm trying to solve is the mapping between pixels on a camera sensor to points in 3D space (which is why zc, the distance from the camera to the point in the camera frame and therefore the norm of the point and camera coordinates in the world frame) using a pinhole camera model.

@Reinderien  x,y,z and x,y,z_t is the position of the point and camera in the world frame. p_x,y is the coordinates of the pixels in the sensor frame (and pixel units) and x,y_p the same points but in the camera frame in whatever unit of length the other points are defined in.

follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78652423/finding-the-camera-pose-from-the-projection-matrix

Prefer stand-alone functions over a closure.
Don't name a variable vars; that's a built-in.
Rephrase your inner f1/f2/f3 with an actual matrix product.
Calculate most of x_p and y_p outside of the cost function, other than the f denominator which is parametric.
Re.

I think that they are infeasible because from the image used for the calibration (with the +ve Z axis pointing into the page) we can see that z_t should be negative.

If you truly believe this, then you should adjust the bounds to force z_t negative - but if you do, the fit is broken. If you leave it unbounded, the fit succeeds. Therefore I believe this to be a problem in your interpretation and not with the code.

Additionally when I substitute the values of x_t, y_t, z_t, psi, theta and phi I found into the original equation it does not fit the data.

With the below, comparing the matrix product with xyz there is an error of roughly 1 part in 40.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares, Bounds


def params_to_matrix(
    angles: np.ndarray, f: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    sinphi, sintheta, sinpsi = np.sin(angles)
    cosphi, costheta, cospsi = np.cos(angles)

    A = np.array((
        (cospsi*costheta, cospsi*sintheta*cosphi - sinpsi*cosphi, cospsi*sintheta*cosphi + sinpsi*sinphi),
        (sinpsi*sintheta, sinpsi*sintheta*sinphi + cospsi*cosphi, sinpsi*sintheta*cosphi - cospsi*sinphi),
        (      -sintheta,        costheta*sinphi,                        costheta*cosphi),
    ))
    A[:, :2] /= f
    return A.T


def equations(
    params: np.ndarray,
    xy_pf: np.ndarray,
    xyz: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    xyzt, angles, (f,) = np.split(params, (3, 6))
    zc = np.linalg.norm(xyzt - xyz, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    A = params_to_matrix(angles, f)

    # Homogeneous affine: rotation transform
    xy1 = np.hstack((xy_pf, np.ones_like(zc)))
    f123 = xy1@A * zc + xyzt - xyz

    return f123.ravel()


def calibrate(
    p_xy: np.ndarray, xyz: np.ndarray,
    refx: float, imgx: int, imgy: int,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, float, np.ndarray]:
    '''
    Homogeneous affine: resolution transform, e.g.
    array([
       [ 0.00273437,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.00273437],
       [-1.75      ,  1.42460937]])
    '''
    res_transform = refx * np.array((
        ( 1/imgx,             0),
        (      0,       -1/imgx),
        (   -0.5, 0.5*imgy/imgx),
    ))
    xy1 = np.hstack((p_xy, np.ones((p_xy.shape[0], 1))))
    xy_pf = xy1 @ res_transform

    result = least_squares(
        fun=equations,
        args=(xy_pf, xyz),
        x0=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=(-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, 2.5),
            ub=( np.inf,  np.inf,  np.inf,  np.inf,  np.inf,  np.inf, 30),
        ),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    xyzt, angles, (f,) = np.split(result.x, (3, 6))
    A = params_to_matrix(angles, f)

    print(result.message)
    print('iterations =', result.nfev)
    return xyzt, np.rad2deg(angles), f, A


def test() -> None:
    coords = np.array((
        ( 234,  347,   30,   25,    8),
        ( 981,  336,  -40,   25,    8),
        (1011,  607,  -40,    0,   -8),
        ( 249,  619,   30,    0,   -8),
        ( 240,  455,   30,   15,    0),
        ( 943,  443,  -35,   15,    0),
        ( 688,  612,  -10,    0,   -8),
        ( 675,  448,  -10,   15,    0),
        ( 665,  340,  -10,   25,    8),
        ( 234,  347,   30,   25,    8),
        ( 981,  336,  -40,   25,    8),
        (1011,  607,  -40,    0,   -8),
        ( 249,  619,   30,    0,   -8),
        ( 240,  455,   30,   15,    0),
        ( 943,  443,  -35,   15,    0),
        ( 688,  612,  -10,    0,   -8),
        ( 675,  448,  -10,   15,    0),
        ( 665,  340,  -10,   25,    8),
    ))
    p_xy, xyz = np.split(coords, (2,), axis=1)

    xyzt, angles, f, A = calibrate(
        p_xy=p_xy, xyz=xyz,
        refx=3.5, imgx=1280, imgy=1024,
    )
    print('x_t, y_t, z_t =', xyzt)
    print('phi, theta, psi =', angles)
    print(f'f = {f:.3f}')
    print('A =')
    print(A)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

`ftol` termination condition is satisfied.
iterations = 99
x_t, y_t, z_t = [  69.41747339   19.54851824 1009.3047241 ]
phi, theta, psi = [   0.31724633 -175.68475553    3.50880635]
f = 30.000
A =
[[-3.31765289e-02 -1.53502740e-04  2.50813472e-03]
 [-4.54342839e-03  3.32694868e-02 -1.84042275e-04]
 [-7.47629650e-02 -1.01315967e-02 -9.97149863e-01]]

Comparison:
>>> A @ np.vstack((         xy_pf, np.ones_like(zc),     ))*zc + xyzt[:, np.newaxis]
array([[ 2.93590616e+01, -3.92480583e+01, -4.03283384e+01,
         3.07633070e+01,  2.98525260e+01, -3.51973240e+01,
        -1.00712603e+01, -1.02926056e+01, -1.01085673e+01,
         2.93590616e+01, -3.92480583e+01, -4.03283384e+01,
         3.07633070e+01,  2.98525260e+01, -3.51973240e+01,
        -1.00712603e+01, -1.02926056e+01, -1.01085673e+01],
       [ 2.45923624e+01,  2.53313483e+01,  1.98082849e-01,
        -5.22180537e-01,  1.47106969e+01,  1.55198594e+01,
        -8.92821244e-02,  1.51728170e+01,  2.50733644e+01,
         2.45923624e+01,  2.53313483e+01,  1.98082849e-01,
        -5.22180537e-01,  1.47106969e+01,  1.55198594e+01,
        -8.92821244e-02,  1.51728170e+01,  2.50733644e+01],
       [ 7.18552816e+00,  7.16060064e+00, -8.49569085e+00,
        -8.71970492e+00, -7.03291839e-01, -4.39907411e-01,
        -7.99110692e+00, -4.01415850e-02,  7.78430899e+00,
         7.18552816e+00,  7.16060064e+00, -8.49569085e+00,
        -8.71970492e+00, -7.03291839e-01, -4.39907411e-01,
        -7.99110692e+00, -4.01415850e-02,  7.78430899e+00]])

>>> xyz
array([[ 30, -40, -40,  30,  30, -35, -10, -10, -10,  30, -40, -40,  30,
         30, -35, -10, -10, -10],
       [ 25,  25,   0,   0,  15,  15,   0,  15,  25,  25,  25,   0,   0,
         15,  15,   0,  15,  25],
       [  8,   8,  -8,  -8,   0,   0,  -8,   0,   8,   8,   8,  -8,  -8,
          0,   0,  -8,   0,   8]])


Running your code I get the exact same outputs from the least squares regression but I don't get the same xyz's as you when calculating them using the matrix A. Firstly the way you calculated xyz doesn't work on my machine because of the shapes of xy_pf & zc (18,2 & 18,1) and when I attempt to fix it as A @ np.transpose(np.hstack((         xy_pf, np.ones_like(zc),     ))*zc) + xyzt[:, np.newaxis] I get very different values from you (that are very incorrect)


You can use other initial guesses: (0, 0, 0, 90, 45, 45, 5)
You can also increase max_nfev=5000.
Make sure the equations are correct.

Code
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from math import sin, cos, radians, degrees


def calibrate(coords, img_shape=(1042, 1280), pixel_size=3.5 / 1280):
    def equations(vars):
        x_t, y_t, z_t, phi, theta, psi, f = vars
        phi, theta, psi = radians(phi), radians(theta), radians(psi)

        a1 = [cos(theta) * cos(psi), cos(theta) * sin(psi), -sin(theta)]
        a2 = [sin(phi) * sin(theta) * cos(psi) - cos(phi) * sin(psi),
              sin(phi) * sin(theta) * sin(psi) + cos(phi) * cos(psi),
              sin(phi) * cos(theta)]
        a3 = [cos(phi) * sin(theta) * cos(psi) + sin(phi) * sin(psi),
              cos(phi) * sin(theta) * sin(psi) - sin(phi) * cos(psi),
              cos(phi) * cos(theta)]
        A = np.array([a1, a2, a3])

        x_p = (p_x - img_shape[1] / 2) * pixel_size / f
        y_p = (-p_y + img_shape[0] / 2) * pixel_size / f

        zc = np.sqrt((x_t - x) ** 2 + (y_t - y) ** 2 + (z_t - z) ** 2)

        f1 = A[0, 0] * x_p + A[0, 1] * y_p + A[0, 2] * zc + x_t - x
        f2 = A[1, 0] * x_p + A[1, 1] * y_p + A[1, 2] * zc + y_t - y
        f3 = A[2, 0] * x_p + A[2, 1] * y_p + A[2, 2] * zc + z_t - z

        return np.hstack([f1, f2, f3])

    p_x, p_y = coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1]
    x, y, z = coords[:, 2], coords[:, 3], coords[:, 4]
    b1 = [-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -180, -90, -180, 2.5]
    b2 = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 180, 90, 180, 30]
    bounds = (b1, b2)
    result = least_squares(fun=equations, x0=(0, 0, 0, 90, 45, 45, 5), max_nfev=5000, loss='soft_l1', bounds=bounds)
    values = result.x
    values[3:6] = (np.degrees(values[3:6])) % 360

    print(result.message)
    print('x_t, y_t, z_t = ', values[:3])
    print('phi, theta, psi = ', values[3:6])
    print('f = ', values[6])
    print('Nb of iterations = ', result.nfev)
    return values


coords = np.array([
    [234, 347, 30, 25, 8], [981, 336, -40, 25, 8], [1011, 607, -40, 0, -8],
    [249, 619, 30, 0, -8], [240, 455, 30, 15, 0], [943, 443, -35, 15, 0],
    [688, 612, -10, 0, -8], [675, 448, -10, 15, 0], [665, 340, -10, 25, 8]
])

calibrate(coords)


Prints
`ftol` termination condition is satisfied.
x_t, y_t, z_t =  [666.02810705   8.43696412   5.21742965]
phi, theta, psi =  [193.12423469  75.72111589 175.07110753]
f =  2.5000000000000004
Nb of iterations =  1646



Comment
@Nick ODell says

I would advise against using bounds on angles here. It creates the possibility the solution will get stuck at one edge, unable to understand that it needs to move to the other side of the search space to get an equivalent angle. Since we're converting this into a canonical angle afterwards anyway, there's no harm in letting the angles be unbounded.

Code
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from math import sin, cos, radians, degrees


def calibrate(coords, img_shape=(1042, 1280), pixel_size=3.5 / 1280):
    def equations(vars):
        x_t, y_t, z_t, phi, theta, psi, f = vars
        phi, theta, psi = radians(phi), radians(theta), radians(psi)

        a1 = [cos(theta) * cos(psi), cos(theta) * sin(psi), -sin(theta)]
        a2 = [sin(phi) * sin(theta) * cos(psi) - cos(phi) * sin(psi),
              sin(phi) * sin(theta) * sin(psi) + cos(phi) * cos(psi),
              sin(phi) * cos(theta)]
        a3 = [cos(phi) * sin(theta) * cos(psi) + sin(phi) * sin(psi),
              cos(phi) * sin(theta) * sin(psi) - sin(phi) * cos(psi),
              cos(phi) * cos(theta)]
        A = np.array([a1, a2, a3])

        x_p = (p_x - img_shape[1] / 2) * pixel_size / f
        y_p = (-p_y + img_shape[0] / 2) * pixel_size / f

        zc = np.sqrt((x_t - x) ** 2 + (y_t - y) ** 2 + (z_t - z) ** 2)

        f1 = A[0, 0] * x_p + A[0, 1] * y_p + A[0, 2] * zc + x_t - x
        f2 = A[1, 0] * x_p + A[1, 1] * y_p + A[1, 2] * zc + y_t - y
        f3 = A[2, 0] * x_p + A[2, 1] * y_p + A[2, 2] * zc + z_t - z

        return np.hstack([f1, f2, f3])

    p_x, p_y = coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1]
    x, y, z = coords[:, 2], coords[:, 3], coords[:, 4]
    result = least_squares(fun=equations, x0=(0, 0, 0, 90, 45, 45, 5), max_nfev=5000, loss='soft_l1')
    values = result.x
    values[3:6] = (np.degrees(values[3:6])) % 360

    print(result.message)
    print('x_t, y_t, z_t = ', values[:3])
    print('phi, theta, psi = ', values[3:6])
    print('f = ', values[6])
    print('Nb of iterations = ', result.nfev)
    return values


coords = np.array([
    [234, 347, 30, 25, 8], [981, 336, -40, 25, 8], [1011, 607, -40, 0, -8],
    [249, 619, 30, 0, -8], [240, 455, 30, 15, 0], [943, 443, -35, 15, 0],
    [688, 612, -10, 0, -8], [675, 448, -10, 15, 0], [665, 340, -10, 25, 8]
])

calibrate(coords)


Prints
`ftol` termination condition is satisfied.
x_t, y_t, z_t =  [  4816.87498307 -40372.26271823  19610.61044526]
phi, theta, psi =  [160.96488438 351.36630016 282.59834487]
f =  0.029689494366122636
Nb of iterations =  570


I would advise against using bounds on angles here. It creates the possibility the solution will get stuck at one edge, unable to understand that it needs to move to the other side of the search space to get an equivalent angle. Since we're converting this into a canonical angle afterwards anyway, there's no harm in letting the angles be unbounded.

Your A[0, 2] * zc term is wrong. In OP's formulation zc applies to all three terms.

Actually, I might not edit that - you might have fixed a parenthesis problem in OP's formula; I'm not in a good position to perform deeper validation of what they wrote. It's possible that your independent-zc is more geometrically sensible, but with the limited theoretical background that OP has provided it's difficult for me to say.

@Reinderien Thanks! I guess OP can figure it out.
