Finding the Camera pose from the projection matrix
I am trying to determine the projection matrix and then the camera pose using a set of object coordinates in a world frame and their corresponding pixel coordinates on an image. Through online resources I have found that you can rewrite the projection equations in the form AP = 0 where A is a matrix containing the information on the pixel and world coordinates and P is the projection matrix in the form of a 12 by 1 vector. This I've seen solved using a least squares regression, in the form of an eigenvalue problem or using singular value decomposition and all of the methods seem to give the same p.
I have the following code:
import numpy as np

class cal:
    def __init__(self, coords):
        
        if coords[:,0].shape[0] < 6: raise ValueError('Not enough observation points, 6 or more required')

        uv, xyz = np.split(coords, (2,), axis = 1)

        self.A = np.zeros((2*coords.shape[0],12))

        for i in range(coords.shape[0]):
            self.A[i*2:i*2 + 2,:] = np.vstack((np.concatenate([xyz[i,:], np.ones(1), np.zeros((4)), -uv[i,0]*np.hstack((xyz[i,:], 1))]),
                                               np.concatenate([np.zeros((4)), xyz[i,:], np.ones(1), -uv[i,1]*np.hstack((xyz[i,:], 1))])))

        
        eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(self.A.T @ self.A)
        min_eig = np.argmin(eig_val)
        self.p = eig_vec[:,min_eig].reshape((3,4))
        
        R_inv, k_inv = np.linalg.qr(np.linalg.inv(self.p[:,:3]))

        self.R = R_inv.T
        self.k = np.linalg.inv(k_inv)
        self.k /= self.k[-1,-1]

        self.T = -np.linalg.inv(self.p[:,:3]) @ self.p[:,-1]

        print('Camera matrix is:')
        print(self.k)
        print('Rotation matrix is:')
        print(self.R)
        print('Camera position is:')
        print(self.T)

    def get_uv(self, xyz: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

        uv_homg = self.p @ np.hstack((xyz, np.ones_like(xyz[:,0:1]))).T
        
        uv_norm = uv_homg / uv_homg[2,:]

        print('u, v are:')
        print(uv_norm[:-1,:])

        return uv_norm

    def get_xyz(self, uv, zc):

        uv_homg = np.hstack((uv, np.ones_like(uv[:,0:1]))).T

        k_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.k)

        xyz_c = k_inv @ uv_homg

        xyz_c *= zc

        
        xyz = self.R.T @ (xyz_c - self.T[np.newaxis,:].T)
        print('x, y, z via k, r and t are:')
        print(xyz)
       

        xyz = np.linalg.pinv(self.p) @ uv_homg * zc 
        xyz /= xyz[-1,0]

        print('x, y, z via pinv are:')
        print(xyz)

        return xyz

Using the following data:
(in the form [pixel coordinates u and v, world coordinates x,y,z in mm])
coords = np.array([[678,   716,     0,     0,     0 ],
[676,   628,     0,     0,    18.67],
[675,   528,     0,     0,    37.33],
[677,   419,     0,     0,    56  ],
[745,   651,    16.67,   0,     0  ],
[804,   599,    37.33,   0,     0  ],
[854,   558,    56,     0,     0  ],
[595,   666,     0,    16.67,   0  ],
[519,   625,     0,    37.33,   0  ],
[449,   588,     0,    56,     0  ],
[748,   573,    16.67,   0,    16.67],
[808,   524,    37.33,   0,    16.67],
[859,   484,    56,     0,    16.67],
[748,   478,    16.67,   0,    37.33],
[813,   432,    37.33,   0,    37.33],
[869,   391,    56,     0,    37.33],
[752,   374,    16.67,   0,    56  ],
[819,   331,    37.33,   0,    56  ],
[877,   295,    56,     0,    56  ],
[590,   584,     0,    16.67,  16.67],
[512,   544,     0,    37.33,  16.67],
[439,   508,     0,    56,    16.67],
[585,   488,     0,    16.67,  37.33],
[501,   451,     0,    37.33,  37.33],
[425,   417,     0,    56,    37.33],
[581,   385,     0,    16.67,  56  ],
[488,   348,     0,    37.33,  56  ],
[408,   318,     0,    56,    56  ],
[660,   340,    16.67,  16.67,  56  ],
[643,   275,    37.33,  37.33,  56  ],
[631,   225,    56,    56,    56  ],
[727,   301,    37.33,  16.67,  56  ],
[568,   309,    16.67,  37.33,  56  ],
[492,   279,    16.67,  56,    56  ],
[567,   250,    37.33,  56,    56  ],
[787,   271,    56,    16.67,  56  ],
[704,   247,    56,    37.33,  56  ]])

sensx = 8.65                   # sensor size in the x direction
imgx, imgy =  (1440,1080)      # image size in pixels
mx = imgx/sensx
index = 28

cal = cal(coords)

cal.get_uv(coords[index,2:][np.newaxis,:])

cal.get_xyz(coords[index,:2][np.newaxis,:], np.linalg.norm(coords[index,2:] - cal.T))

print('calculated f is')
print(cal.k[0,0]/mx)


I get:
(testing with the following point: [660,   340,    16.67,  16.67,  56]
Camera matrix is:
[[ 1.10085803e+03 -8.97333229e+00  7.11294043e+02]
 [-0.00000000e+00 -1.09218290e+03  4.21825076e+02]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
Rotation matrix is:
[[-0.60453385  0.79650852 -0.0106299 ]
 [-0.38712166 -0.30542782 -0.86997165]
 [-0.6961865  -0.52181225  0.49298715]]
Camera position is:
[-103.60456911  -83.9594023   130.69993225]
u, v are:
[[658.26719869]
 [344.14651874]]
x, y, z via k, r and t are:
[[-125.28143248]
 [  24.10266151]
 [ -64.18072346]]
x, y, z via pinv are:
[[33.74160228]
 [30.52774348]
 [46.34949045]
 [ 1.        ]]
calculated f is
8.817057341328972

Firstly looking at the camera matrix k, in theory k[0,1] should be 0 or close to it which it is not. The locations of the image centre u_x, u_y k[0,2] and k[1,2] should be in the centre of the image and therefore imgx/2 and imgy/2, we can see that u_x is approximately correct however u_y is quite far of (should be 540).
The camera position looks correct to me (it is the approximate position where I took the picture).
u and v are close to within a couple of pixels.
The focal length f is incorrect as I took the picture with my phone with a focal length of 4mm.
However when I calculate the world coordinates based of of the pixel coordinates (and the depth from the camera) using two methods,

taking the projection of the pixels in the camera frame using the depth and k and then transforming into the world frame using R and T
Directly inverting the equation [u,v,1] = P [x,y,z,1] using the pseudo-inverse of P
but neither are giving the correct world coordinates

Additionally I took R and T and plotted the camera reference frame in the world reference frame I get the following:

From the way I defined my axes the +ve z axis (in blue) is the optical axis of the camera and therefore should be pointing (roughly) towards the origin of the world frame which it is not which leads me to guess that the rotation matrix is incorrect. Both the world and camera coordinate frames are right handed, the sensor and camera frames are the same with only a translation from the sensor frame (top right corner of the image) to the camera frame centered on the principal point of the image.
Does anybody know what I have done wrong? The fact that the projection matrix gives the correct pixel coordinates but having the issues with the intrinsic/extrinsic matrices leads me to believe that my decomposition of the projection matrix is incorrect.

context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78596311/solving-a-set-of-non-linear-equations-by-fitting-to-a-dataset

@Theo if this question means you solved your previous question, either accept the answer that allowed you to move forward, or write the answer that you ended up figuring out yourself, instead. Don't just post new questions without resolving your previous one. Stackoverflow only works if you upvote useful answers, downvote bad answers, and accept "the answer that helped you fix things".

The other post isn’t very relevant because it’s a different implementation. I didn’t accept any answers because they didn’t  fix my problem and hence why I’m posting this one.

Remember that if no answers actually answer your question, then your question isn't clear enough and you need to edit it so that people can't answer with unrelated or inapplicable solutions. This is not a one-way street where you just post questions until you have an answer, you are equally responsible for helping others understand what you need help with.
